# Disable Eset Smart Security using metasploit

Tags: windows, cmd, windows-services, metasploit

Im trying to disable Eset Smart Security 7, in order to do this I have to shutdown his service ekrn.exe so I started with this:

```
sc queryex ekrn

SERVICE_NAME: ekrn
    TYPE               : 110  WIN32_OWN_PROCESS  (interactive)
    STATE              : 4  RUNNING
                             (NOT_STOPPABLE, NOT_PAUSABLE, ACCEPTS_SHUTDOWN)
    WIN32_EXIT_CODE    : 0  (0x0)
    SERVICE_EXIT_CODE  : 0  (0x0)
    CHECKPOINT         : 0x0
    WAIT_HINT          : 0x0
    PID                : 1696
    FLAGS              :
```

Because it is a non-stoppable and non-pausable but accepts shutdown I attempted to disable it from startup so next time I reboot it will not start so I did this:

```
sc config ekrn start= disabled

[SC] ChangeServiceConfig ERROR 5:
Acces Denied
```

Im doing this as NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM so I dont know why this error pops up. Any help would be apreciated.

Im doing all this from a remote shell using metasploit in a virtual windows 7